# Geometric Series, Common Difference as relationship between terms

Tags: geometric-series

I'm self-studying maths, so have turned to the good people of MSE as I have no teacher to ask.

I completed the following problem and didn't find it difficult. However, the answer provided in the text book is different, and I can't see what I've done wrong. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**The Question**

$x$, $3$, and $x + 8$ are the fourth, fifth and sixth terms of a geometric series.
a) Find two possible values of $x$ and corresponding values of common ratio.
b) Given sum to infinity exists, find first term
c) Find sum to infinity

**My Solution**

a) I used the fact of the relationship between consecutive terms in a geometric series.

i.e. $\frac{U2} {U1}$ = $\frac{U3} {U2}$ ... $\frac{U5} {U4}$ = $\frac{U6} {U5}$
So: $\frac{3} {x} = \frac{x + 8} {3}$, so $x = 1$ or $x = -9$

Substituting $x$ into $\frac{U5} {U4}$ in the above: $r = 3$ or $r = \frac {-1} {3}$

Parts b) and c) follow from results in a) so no need to consider them.

**The Text Book**

$ar^3 = x$

$ar^4 = 3$

$ar^5 = x + 8$

So: $\frac {ar^5} {ar^4} = \frac {ar^4} {ar^3}$

They then express this as $\frac {x + 8} {3} = \frac{3} {x}$, and find the same values for $x$.

However, book says $r = $ $\frac {ar^4} {ar^3}$ $=$ $\frac{x} {3}$ thus giving $r = \frac{1} {3}, r = -3.$ for the found values of $x$

I can't fathom why the method I used is wrong. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be $r=\frac {ar^4} {ar^3}=\frac{3} {x}$

Comment: Thanks. So just to be crystal clear for my understanding of the topic: 1) It's a typo in the book; 2) The logic of my solution was correct?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo and your solution is correct.

Comment: Thanks both of you.